# Why does zsh lose autocomplete for file paths when I'm in a flag and how can I get it back?

Tags: zsh

The program that I am trying to run takes the form `program_name --arg=/some/path/goes/here`, but zsh cannot perform tab completion on that path when it is in the argument flag. I end up having to type `progra<TAB> /so<TAB>/pa<TAB>...` to complete the path and then go back to add the `--arg=` part of the command. Is there a more efficient way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that zsh is still trying to do file completion in your situation, it's just considering the `--arg=` to be the initial part of the file name causing it to not find any matches. Since there aren't any universal rules for how commands will interpret their arguments the safest option is for the shell to not make any assumptions about those arguments.

Many commands which use that type of syntax will work the same if you use a space rather than the `=` sign, such as `program_name --arg /some/path/goes/here`. Since that would be a separate argument the shell should be able to do file completion without issues.

Depending on how you have zsh configured, it may also work to use `setopt MAGIC_EQUAL_SUBST`. I normally have that option set and get the behavior that you are looking for, but get the behavior that you currently experience if I unset that option. But, if I use `zsh -f` to skip loading my configuration just enabling that option isn't sufficient so there is apparently something else in my config that was necessary, possibly just the enabling of the completion system which you would likely have done already. There could be cases where this would result in undesirable behavior, but I haven't run into any in the many years that I've been using zsh with that option set.

A more complicated option would be to write a completion function for that command which tells zsh that that option takes a file name as the argument.